# How to include the same JPanel on every Swing Page

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, code-reuse

How to include a standard panel of buttons (like on top of every page 'Print', 'New' etc) on every Java Swing page using Java?

Comment: *"Quick answer required."*  Patience required.  Voting to close as 'too localized - ..a specific moment in time'.

Comment: What have you done till now? SO is not machine which print's code by your wish.

Comment: Actually I am want to include same panel on every page without making a new Panel. Just to include panel on every page.

Comment: Brano88 ...I am new in Java swings and just playing with swing components.

Comment: BTW - What Java class DYM by 'page'?   A `JPanel`, `JDialog`, `JFrame`..?

Comment: "Quick answer required" is a bit too demanding for someone asking for help from volunteers. Next time I suggest you consider a softer less demanding tone. Either that or pay for your help and demand all you'd like.

Comment: I am sorry by writing unintentially the word 'Quick answer'. sorry for that.

Comment: I have deleted it. I recommend that if you're still stuck, ask a new question, but in this question, describe in greater detail just what you're trying to do, show us what you've tried and tell us how it isn't working. The more useful information you can give us in your question, the better we'll be able to help you. Luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class that will extend JPanel, place your buttons in it and declare their standart behavior.
2. Extend this class in every "look-alike class you want" you create.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) and add buttons to it.

```
JToolBar jToolBar = new JToolBar();
JButton jButtonFileOpen = new JButton();
jToolBar.add(jButtonFileOpen);
```